# Resolution independence - resize on the fly or ship all sizes?

Tags: textures, resolution, rendertargets

My game relies heavily on textures of various sizes with some being full-screen. The game is targeted for multiple resolutions. I found that resizing textures (downsizing) works quite well for this game’s art type (it’s not Pixel Art or anything like that). I asked my artist to ensure that all textures at the edges of the screen to be created in such a way that they can safely “overflow” off screen; this means that aspect ratio is not an issue.

So with no aspect ratio issues, I figured that I would simply ask my artist to create assets in very high resolution, and then resize them down to the appropriate screen resolution. The question is, *when* and *how* do I do that?

Do I pre-resize everything to common resolutions in Photoshop and package *all* assets in the final product (increasing the size download that the user has to deal with) and then select the appropriate asset based on the detected resolution? Or do I ship with the largest set of Textures, detect the resolution on load, set a render target and draw all downsized assets to it and use that? Or for the latter, do I use some sort of a CPU-sided algorithm to resize on game load?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you do what you need and that requires testing and/or some thought:

- Does your platform allow pre-rendering all different sizes, perhaps with manual touch-up when needed, or will the distribution simply be too big?
- Does your platform incur too much of a performance hit using the largest assets at all times?
- Can you do a platform-based resize during initialization of the game (pre-render on load) to avoid the above if it applies?
- Does your platform allow you to resize assets in a way that looks acceptable to you?
- If it looks good and performs well enough - just go with it

Sometimes having a few different major sizes pre-rendered is a good idea - a 256x256 pixel bitmap won't resize favourably to 16x16 or even 32x32 unless an artist does it by hand - so perhaps you should have two or three vastly different sizes from your artist and pick the one that's the best fit at run-time.

Comment: Is there a systematic approach to determining what the downsize threshold is? For example, going from 256x256 to 12x128 is ok, but to 16x16 is not. Is this pretty much limited to a visual inspection?